# ReSharper shortcut to navigate between hints

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

ReSharper has F12 as default key to navigate between Error/Warnings, but it skips the "hints".

Is there another shortcut to include the hints in the navigation or an option to include them in the F12 research?

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct operations for this navigation in Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard

`ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoNextErrorInSolution` sounds like what is currently bound to your F12.

`ReSharper.ReSharper_GotoNextHighlight` sounds like what what you want.

In this window, it's possible to bind these two operations to whatever key combinations you want.

[image: Keyboard options]

Comment: Unfortunately this works just for suggestions, not for hints.

Comment: @user4388177 ah, apologies. Is it a specific type of hint you want to highlight, or all hints? It's possible to upgrade individual types of hint to warnings, which would cover that case.

Comment: all the hints; I would prefer to keep them hints if I can, but it's a good workaround, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [default keymap reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html#code_analysis), you can use <kbd>F12</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for errors/warnings in the file, or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for the solution.